# How to make the overlay be active only on the image and not on a whole column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

So I'm working on a local project and not intending on releasing it but... How do I make the overlay only show on the image and not on the whole column. I found this pre-built code on the w3 schools website and I'm intending on it to work. On top of html and css, I also use bootstrap v5.0

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}
  
  .image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: black;
  }
  
  .container:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 0.65;
  }
  
  .text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-4 col-lg-2 personal-grid">
    <div class="card ms-4 me-4 shadow-sm card">
        <a class="image" href="#"><img class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top d-sm-block d-md-block d-lg-none cardsize"  src="images/blackopsm.jpg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"></img></a>
        <a class="" href="#"><img class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-block hidecard" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"  src="images/call-of-duty-black-ops-steam.jpg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"></img></a>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Call of Duty: Black Ops</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wanted the hover overlay to only be shown on the image, but instead on the whole column was filled with the overlay

Comment: I would personally put the img and overlay together in a div. And give the overlay `position: absolute;` and the div (where the img and overlay are in) a `position: relative;

Comment: I don't understand. Can you re-explain it please??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally put the img and overlay together in a div. And give the overlay `position: absolute;` and the div (where the img and overlay are in) a `position: relative;`

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content; 
    height: fit-content;
    /* `fit-content`so the container has the same size as the img */
}
.overlay  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 51, 255, 0.267);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* `100%`so the overlay has the same size as the container */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1481349518771-20055b2a7b24?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cmFuZG9tfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
 </div>
```